# How to upload cached app data when there's a network connection?

Tags: ios, caching, upload

I want to be able to save some data from my app then upload it to a server when there's a Wifi connection. Is there a standard way of doing this? Also, is it possible to do this even if my app has been shutdown in the meantime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Reachability library to check if you're connected to a network or not, if not save the data either in the SQLite datebase or another method you are already saving it. On app launch or when a network is detected check if there is cached data and then send it in a request, deleting the data after getting a confirmation from the server that it was successfully received.

Link to Reachability: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: So there's no way of doing this if my app has been shutdown?

Comment: You can do this in the app delegate, it has a few methods for when the app is about to exit/start/come in and out of the background, but no if the app is shutdown already you cant do it until it reopened.